# "TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes" when running npx expo start and opening expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-hermes

After creating a react native project using **npx create-expo-app** command, I tried to launch **npx expo start** as stated in the documentation. I ran into the following error in my console after I scanned the QR code with my android phone through the expo app.
[image]

I upgraded expo with `expo update`, it installed the following versions.
[image]

I see in the expo documentation that the version 48 has Hermes by default.
I tried to put `"hermesEnabled": false` in app.json, but I get the same error.

I also tried to delete node_modules and cleared cache with `yarn cache clean`

I didn't do any implementation, just created a default app several times and I get the same error.
The application is launching on a web browser, but I want to use it through the expo app.

What could be the issue? Did I miss any command lines?

Thank you,

Comment: Any update on that ? I upgraded RN as well, and got this issue too